# Checking if multiple conditions are met in a column based on all rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am currently trying to create an excel test plan for our test team, I want to be able to input a description, Tester undertaking, start date and the days it will take.

I currently have the following but I want to add a condition in to highlight where the tester will have days that overlap. I have highlighted them myself but would want these to display in a different colour.

[image]

I currently have the following conditional formatting:

```
=AND(E$2>=$C4,E$2<=WORKDAY($C4,$D4-1))
```

I'm struggling to work out what the conditional format would be so that any day that a person is required on 2 pieces of work it will highlight in a new colour.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution which works if the cells contain "Yes" when the tester is working.  You can probably adapt it to work for blank cells by nesting your existing formula.

```
    =AND(COUNTIFS($C$5:$C$10,$C5,F$5:F$10,"YES")>1,F5="YES")
```

Where column C is Tester and cell F5 has the conditional format.

I can't post an image of the solution because I am new to the site and don't have enough reputation!

Answer (score 0):

A very ugly solution for starters, I'll try and refine it:

For each row, make an array like so:

> =SEQUENCE(,WORKDAY(C5,D5)-C5,C5)&B5

This will generate an array with the dates of the green boxes, with each date 'tagged' with the the respective tester.

Next, I stacked each row's array into one large array. Because I produced these arrays in the AZ column, this formula for me was

> =HSTACK(AZ5#:AZ11#)

I put this large array in AZ13. Now, you can use conditional formatting to identify your duplicate dates:

> =AND(COUNTIF($AZ$13#, E$2&$B5)>1,AND(E$2>=$C5,E$2<=WORKDAY($C5,$D5-1)))

The first half of the outer AND function identifies dates which occur in the large array more than once, whilst the second half restricts this formatting to already green squares using your pre-existing formatting (note I changed $C5 to $C4).

Like I said, I'll try and think of a neater solution. Let me know if the above is clear enough and works for you.

[image: picture of solution]